# My write method cant be called in loop menu

Tags: java, methods, menu, filewriter

this is a section of my menu

```
   if (opt == 5)
       writeFile(myCar);
```

this is the method itself

```
public static void writeFile(String CarDatabase, String text, Car [] myCar) throws IOException {
    File file = new File (CarDatabase);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    out.write(text);
    out.close();
}
```

and this is the error i receive

```
writeFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,Car[]) in Cars cannot be applied to (Car[])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call the method which accepts exactly parameters of type `String`, `String` and `Car[]` in that order but are only passing a `Car[]` object. You need to pass in two other Strings to the method, or define some other method which accepts only your `Car[]` array.

Comment: but when i change it to if (opt == 5) writeFile(CarDatabase, text, myCar); i then receive cannot find symbol errros for them both what should i put in the brackets to fix it?

Comment: @Wasim Cannot find symbol in your case likely means that the method cannot see either the `CarDatabase` string or the `text` String. You need to declare them locally or in a place the method can see. Just do a quick read up on Java access modifiers. It'll clear up your questions.

Comment: can you please just tell me what I need to put in the brackets to make it call the method, im still new to java, so I dont know

Comment: @Wasim Edit your question above to include the full code.

Comment: its too long to format, can i email the file to you?

Answer (score 2):

writeFile method takes 3 arguments, like the error says, yet you try to invoke that method with one argument: `writeFile(myCar);`

Either redefine your method to take one argument or add the two required Strings on method invocation.